# Access to the path '/data/user/0/com.companyname.hidden_wiretapping/files' is denied.'

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, manifest

помогите мне разобраться, я хочу сохранить свою аудиозапись на внешнем хранилище, я дал доступ к android.manifest, а также попросил у пользователя разрешение (CheckPermisissions), но я не могу получить доступ к записи

Вот мой манифест

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.companyname.hidden_wiretapping" android:installLocation="preferExternal">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="18" android:targetSdkVersion="30" />
    <application   android:label="Hidden_Wiretapping.Android" android:theme="@style/MainTheme"></application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
</manifest>
```

Вот мой код, в котором я пытаюсь сохранить аудиозапись в папку

```cs
private async void Start_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!audioRecorderService.IsRecording)
    {
        var mainDir = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        var PermissionsStrorage = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.StorageWrite>();
        var PermissionsMicrophone = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.Microphone>();
        if (PermissionsStrorage != PermissionStatus.Granted && PermissionsMicrophone != PermissionStatus.Granted)
        {
            PermissionsStrorage = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.StorageWrite>();
            PermissionsMicrophone = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.Microphone>();
        }
        if (PermissionsStrorage != PermissionStatus.Granted && PermissionsMicrophone != PermissionStatus.Granted)
        {
            return;
        }
        var file = Path.Combine(mainDir, "count.txt");
        File.Create(file);
                        
        audioRecorderService.TotalAudioTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);
        audioRecorderService.FilePath = mainDir;
        await audioRecorderService.StartRecording();
        Start.TextColor = Color.Blue;
    }
    else
    {
        await audioRecorderService.StopRecording();
        Start.TextColor = Color.Red;
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ разобраться удалось однако на эмуляторе все запустилось , и сохранило файл где мне надо , а на телефоне xiaomi я все так же не могу получить доступ к корневой папке –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`File.Create(file)` возвращает `FileStream`, который `IDisposable` кстати. Вы создаете и открываете файл, и никогда не закрываете. Скорее в других методах вы просто не можете ничего записать в файл вами же открытый.

Если надо создать пустой файл, то можно так

```cs
using (var fs = File.Create(file)) { }
```

Но я не вижу смысла в такой манипуляции. Создавать файл надо как раз при начале записи, а не заранее.

[Документация](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/files/).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ разобраться удалось однако на эмуляторе все запустилось , и сохранило файл где мне надо , а на телефоне xiaomi я все так же не могу получить доступ к корневой папке